# weblogic server failed to start

Tags: java, oracle11g, netbeans-7, weblogic12c

I successfully installed Weblogic server on my machine  and then registered same in netbeans
Now when i started the server from netbeans , i get a list of verbose statements and then  error statements.I need to know how to resolve this problem.Thank you.

```
.
.
JAVA Memory arguments: -Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:CompileThreshold=8000 -XX:PermSize=128m  -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
.
WLS Start Mode=Development
.
CLASSPATH=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\patch_wls1211\profiles\default\sys_manifest_classpath\weblogic_patch.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\patch_ocp371\profiles\default\sys_manifest_classpath\weblogic_patch.jar;C:\KHARES~1\jdk7\lib\tools.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.1\server\lib\weblogic_sp.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.1\server\lib\weblogic.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\modules\features\weblogic.server.modules_12.1.1.0.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.1\server\lib\webservices.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\modules\ORGAPA~1.1/lib/ant-all.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\modules\NETSFA~1.0_1/lib/ant-contrib.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\wlserver_12.1\sip\server\lib\weblogic_sip.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.1\common\derby\lib\derbyclient.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.1\server\lib\xqrl.jar;.;C:\Progra~2\Java\jre6\lib\ext\QTJava.zip
.
PATH=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\patch_wls1211\profiles\default\native;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\patch_ocp371\profiles\default\native;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.1\server\native\win\x64;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.1\server\bin;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\modules\ORGAPA~1.1\bin;C:\KHARES~1\jdk7\jre\bin;C:\KHARES~1\jdk7\bin;C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin;;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\cygwin\bin;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.1\server\native\win\x64\oci920_8
.
***************************************************
*  To start WebLogic Server, use a username and   *
*  password assigned to an admin-level user.  For *
*  server administration, use the WebLogic Server *
*  console at http:\\hostname:port\console        *
***************************************************
starting weblogic with Java version:
java version "1.7.0_02"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_02-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 22.0-b10, mixed mode)
Starting WLS with line:
C:\KHARES~1\jdk7\bin\java -client   -Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:CompileThreshold=8000 -XX:PermSize=128m  -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Dweblogic.Name=AdminServer -Djava.security.policy=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.1\server\lib\weblogic.policy  -Xverify:none -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\KHARES~1\jdk7/jre/lib/endorsed;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.1/endorsed -ea:com.bea.wcp...   -da -Dplatform.home=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.1 -Dwls.home=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.1\server -Dweblogic.home=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.1\server   -Dweblogic.management.discover=true  -Dwlw.iterativeDev= -Dwlw.testConsole= -Dwlw.logErrorsToConsole= -Dweblogic.ext.dirs=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\patch_wls1211\profiles\default\sysext_manifest_classpath;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\patch_ocp371\profiles\default\sysext_manifest_classpath  weblogic.Server
<Aug 22, 2013 10:52:25 PM WAT> <Info> <Security> <BEA-090905> <Disabling CryptoJ JCE Provider self-integrity check for better startup performance. To enable this check, specify -Dweblogic.security.allowCryptoJDefaultJCEVerification=true> 
<Aug 22, 2013 10:52:26 PM WAT> <Info> <Security> <BEA-090906> <Changing the default Random Number Generator in RSA CryptoJ from ECDRBG to FIPS186PRNG. To disable this change, specify -Dweblogic.security.allowCryptoJDefaultPRNG=true> 
<Aug 22, 2013 10:52:26 PM WAT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000395> <The following extensions directory contents added to the end of the classpath: 
C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\base_domain\lib\sipactivator.jar.> 
<Aug 22, 2013 10:52:27 PM WAT> <Info> <Server> <BEA-002647> <The service plug-in, com.oracle.core.sip.activator, was added from C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\base_domain\lib\sipactivator.jar.> 
<Aug 22, 2013 10:52:27 PM WAT> <Info> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000377> <Starting WebLogic Server with Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM Version 22.0-b10 from Oracle Corporation.> 
<Aug 22, 2013 10:52:28 PM WAT> <Info> <Management> <BEA-141107> <Version: WebLogic Server 12.1.1.0  Wed Dec 7 08:40:57 PST 2011 1445491 > 
<Aug 22, 2013 10:52:30 PM WAT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to STARTING.> 
<Aug 22, 2013 10:52:30 PM WAT> <Info> <WorkManager> <BEA-002900> <Initializing self-tuning thread pool.> 
<Aug 22, 2013 10:52:30 PM WAT> <Notice> <LoggingService> <BEA-320400> <The log file C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\base_domain\servers\AdminServer\logs\AdminServer.log will be rotated. Reopen the log file if tailing has stopped. This can happen on some platforms, such as Windows.> 
<Aug 22, 2013 10:52:30 PM WAT> <Notice> <LoggingService> <BEA-320401> <The log file has been rotated to C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\base_domain\servers\AdminServer\logs\AdminServer.log00001. Log messages will continue to be logged in C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\base_domain\servers\AdminServer\logs\AdminServer.log.> 
<Aug 22, 2013 10:52:30 PM WAT> <Notice> <Log Management> <BEA-170019> <The server log file C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\base_domain\servers\AdminServer\logs\AdminServer.log is opened. All server side log events will be written to this file.> 
<Aug 22, 2013 10:52:40 PM WAT> <Warning> <Security> <BEA-090076> <A failure occurred attempting to load LDIF for provider Authorizer from file C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.1\server\lib\XACMLAuthorizerInit.ldift.> 
<Aug 22, 2013 10:52:40 PM WAT> <Error> <Security> <BEA-090870> <The realm "myrealm" failed to be loaded: weblogic.security.service.SecurityServiceException: com.bea.common.engine.ServiceInitializationException: weblogic.security.spi.ProviderInitializationException: A failure occurred attempting to load LDIF for provider Authorizer from file C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.1\server\lib\XACMLAuthorizerInit.ldift..
weblogic.security.service.SecurityServiceException: com.bea.common.engine.ServiceInitializationException: weblogic.security.spi.ProviderInitializationException: A failure occurred attempting to load LDIF for provider Authorizer from file C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.1\server\lib\XACMLAuthorizerInit.ldift.
    at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.initializeRealm(CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.java:466)
    at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.loadRealm(CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.java:841)
    at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.initializeRealms(CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.java:870)
    at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.initialize(CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.java:1032)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityServiceManager.initialize(SecurityServiceManager.java:873)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: com.bea.common.engine.ServiceInitializationException: weblogic.security.spi.ProviderInitializationException: A failure occurred attempting to load LDIF for provider Authorizer from file C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.1\server\lib\XACMLAuthorizerInit.ldift.
    at com.bea.common.engine.internal.ServiceEngineImpl.findOrStartService(ServiceEngineImpl.java:365)
    at com.bea.common.engine.internal.ServiceEngineImpl.findOrStartService(ServiceEngineImpl.java:315)
    at com.bea.common.engine.internal.ServiceEngineImpl.lookupService(ServiceEngineImpl.java:257)
    at com.bea.common.engine.internal.ServicesImpl.getService(ServicesImpl.java:72)
    at weblogic.security.service.CSSWLSDelegateImpl.getService(CSSWLSDelegateImpl.java:155)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: weblogic.security.spi.ProviderInitializationException: A failure occurred attempting to load LDIF for provider Authorizer from file C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.1\server\lib\XACMLAuthorizerInit.ldift.
    at com.bea.common.store.bootstrap.internal.BootStrapServiceImpl.loadFullLDIFTemplate(BootStrapServiceImpl.java:910)
    at com.bea.common.store.bootstrap.internal.BootStrapServiceImpl.loadLDIFTemplate(BootStrapServiceImpl.java:688)
    at com.bea.common.store.bootstrap.internal.BootStrapServiceImpl.loadLDIFXACMLAuthorizerTemplate(BootStrapServiceImpl.java:176)
    at com.bea.common.store.bootstrap.internal.BootStrapServiceImpl.loadLDIFXACMLAuthorizerTemplate(BootStrapServiceImpl.java:160)
    at com.bea.common.security.internal.service.BootStrapServiceImpl.loadLDIFXACMLAuthorizerTemplate(BootStrapServiceImpl.java:106)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: <openjpa-1.1.1-SNAPSHOT-r422266:957329 fatal store error> kodo.jdo.FatalDataStoreException: The transaction has been rolled back.  See the nested exceptions for details on the errors that occurred.
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.newFlushException(BrokerImpl.java:2170)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.flush(BrokerImpl.java:2017)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.flushSafe(BrokerImpl.java:1915)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.beforeCompletion(BrokerImpl.java:1833)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.LocalManagedRuntime.commit(LocalManagedRuntime.java:81)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: <openjpa-1.1.1-SNAPSHOT-r422266:957329 nonfatal store error> kodo.jdo.DataStoreException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
 {prepstmnt 1949463897 INSERT INTO BEAXACMLAP (DOMN, REALMN, TYPEN, CN, XVER, CTS, WCN, WCI, WXF, XD, XS, MTS) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [params=(String) base_domain, (String) myrealm, (String) Policies, (String) urn:bea:xacml:2.0:entitlement:resource:type@E@Fmbean@G, (String) 1.0, (null) null, (null) null, (null) null, (Blob) oracle.sql.BLOB@64edb87a, (InputStream) java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@32ea855a, (String) 3, (Timestamp) 2013-08-22 22:52:40.21] [reused=0]} [code=942, state=42000]
FailedObject: com.bea.common.security.store.data.XACMLAuthorizationPolicy@5c854934
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DBDictionary.narrow(DBDictionary.java:4207)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DBDictionary.newStoreException(DBDictionary.java:4171)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLExceptions.getStore(SQLExceptions.java:102)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLExceptions.getStore(SQLExceptions.java:72)
    at kodo.jdbc.kernel.BatchingPreparedStatementManager.flushInternal(BatchingPreparedStatementManager.java:214)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.ReportingSQLException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
 {prepstmnt 1949463897 INSERT INTO BEAXACMLAP (DOMN, REALMN, TYPEN, CN, XVER, CTS, WCN, WCI, WXF, XD, XS, MTS) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [params=(String) base_domain, (String) myrealm, (String) Policies, (String) urn:bea:xacml:2.0:entitlement:resource:type@E@Fmbean@G, (String) 1.0, (null) null, (null) null, (null) null, (Blob) oracle.sql.BLOB@64edb87a, (InputStream) java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@32ea855a, (String) 3, (Timestamp) 2013-08-22 22:52:40.21] [reused=0]} [code=942, state=42000]
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.LoggingConnectionDecorator.wrap(LoggingConnectionDecorator.java:192)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.LoggingConnectionDecorator.access$700(LoggingConnectionDecorator.java:57)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.LoggingConnectionDecorator$LoggingConnection$LoggingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(LoggingConnectionDecorator.java:866)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:269)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager$CancelPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JDBCStoreManager.java:1421)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
> 
<Aug 22, 2013 10:52:40 PM WAT> <Notice> <Security> <BEA-090082> <Security initializing using security realm myrealm.> 
<Aug 22, 2013 10:52:40 PM WAT> <Critical> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000362> <Server failed. Reason: 

There are 1 nested errors:

weblogic.security.service.SecurityServiceRuntimeException: [Security:090399]Security Services Unavailable
    at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.doBootAuthorization(CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.java:917)
    at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.initialize(CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.java:1054)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityServiceManager.initialize(SecurityServiceManager.java:873)
    at weblogic.security.SecurityService.start(SecurityService.java:148)
    at weblogic.t3.srvr.SubsystemRequest.run(SubsystemRequest.java:64)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)

> 
<Aug 22, 2013 10:52:41 PM WAT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to FAILED.> 
<Aug 22, 2013 10:52:41 PM WAT> <Error> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000383> <A critical service failed. The server will shut itself down.> 
<Aug 22, 2013 10:52:41 PM WAT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to FORCE_SHUTTING_DOWN.>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you create RDBMS tables in the datastore used by the security store? Create scripts can be found in WL_HOME/server/lib. Information provided by http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24422/rdbms.htm#autoId5

Answer (score 0):

OK, I know this thread is old now, but just wanted to share my 2 cents on this: 
I had a similar error recently and after trying a lot of other options I trivially checked the disk drive which was running full! **After freeing some space** off and clearing the server caches and tmp dirs, I was no longer facing this error :)